# how to allocate arrays and 2D arrays with max length by malloc in c while accessing to them?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, multidimensional-array

I am coding a program which takes a text file as an input, makes the index of the words of it and prints the output(the index) in a file and in the screen.

the input file may be huge. but we KNOW that the maximum variety of the words used in the text file is 200. we don't know what's the maximum of lines and characters of each word. so I should reserve a large number for them. I took the maximum of line 1000 and the maximum characters of each word 100.

I am programming in Turbo C and (I am forced to use that). the compiler allocates just 64kb memory (with the size of the compiler included) and so I have to use MALLOC.

my program is supposed to work in this algorithm: it reads the input file line by line with fgets. then in the current line, it reads word by word with strtok. so far I have the xth word in yth line. I want to put the words in an array of pointers. so I need a char * word[200]. and I want to show how many times, which word is repeated in which line. so I need a int index [200][1000]. if in yth line, the xth word is existed I would do index[x][y]++.

so now I need to allocate MALLOC memory to these char * word[200] and int index[200][1000] . Can anyone help? I tried all the answers to such questions and none of them helped.
see errors:

```
char **words;
words = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 200);//cannot conver void * to char **
for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    words[i] = malloc(100);//cannot convert void * to char *

int **index;
index = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 200)//cannot convert void * to int **
for (i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    index[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000);
```

Comment: It sounds like you've thought the program through. Now you need to implement it. It's nice that you're using the copy-pasted code you got from the other question you asked, but I have a question for you: Are you trying to get us to do your homework for you?

Comment: 100 character words?  Are the words in German? :-D

Comment: Throw this out. Use a hash to make a signature of each word that points to a malloc'd linked list of index values where that word is found.

Comment: @JonahNelson that's not my homework. and thanks paying attention. anyway, if u think your are MADE to do something, no it's not like that.

Comment: and I copy pasted coz I am trying all ways to get the problem solved. this code seemed so near to what I wanted. but it still has errors.

Comment: @dawg can you explain more?

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey anything is possible in this world ;)

Comment: @MelikaBarzegaranHosseini If you are not doing homework, please explain why you're forced to use a compiler which hasn't been maintained in nearly 24 years. Also please elaborate on why, when you very clearly described what you intend to do, you seem to have no propensity to create code which is capable of doing it. It seems that you have a good understanding of the task, but I don't see any effort or ability evident as far as completing it.

Comment: @JonahNelson I actually CODED all parts EXCEPT this. I just don't know  how to allocate to arrays and 2D arrays by malloc. I read DEITEL and it didn't helped. I just don't know the syntax and I don't how much more I can make efforts when I have reserched still not found and people here not answering sth usefull.

Comment: @JonahNelson be sure that if I could coded this and knew the syntax, I wouldn't be here persuading people that I am not a person who wants to makes other people does their homework. I would simply go and coded by myself.

Comment: @MelikaBarzegaranHosseini If your problem is not the logic, but rather the syntax, then http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc this should be of infinite use to you.

Comment: @JonahNelson actually SO won't go on without people like you here helping. I know your intention is to help. I give you right to think so. but criticizing people in that stage you do, I don't think that's a good idea. it would be just wasting time here.

Comment: The longest German word is "Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaftskapitän".  Translated to English it means "Danube steamship company captain."

Comment: I actually read the simple syntax that I am here. I don't know what would be syntax for array and 2D array. I just need and example.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey you are lil by lil persuading me to get the max 50. ;)

Comment: @MelikaBarzegaranHosseini `#define BUFFER_SIZE (strlen("Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaftskapitän") + 1)` :-D

Comment: So what to do if the file has a word like this: "kjfdlkasjfdlkjalfdkjlasdjflksajdflkjasdsdkfljsdjfkjashdfkahdkjfhajsdhgfjashdgfkjashdflkjahsdlkfjhkas" ? :D

Comment: Well, I honestly don't understand your problem - the code you post looks fine, at least technically. What's not working?

And concerning the longest word in German; there is none. You can add arbitrary amounts to any german substantive, like Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaftskapitänsmütze (now try googling that one...). And that is my other point: Avoid fixed limits at all costs, your code is bound to be used in contexts where an apparently insanely high limit becomes too small, giving you the bugs of your worst nightmares. No problem comming up with german words of 200 characters and more...

Comment: @cmaster I wrote the compiler errors in the question post. can you help me to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `malloc` function returns a `void *` object, which you can think of as "a pointer to an undefined type". It's C's way of formatting a pointer when you don't know what kind of object it points to.

The errors Turbo C is issuing mean that you're not allowed to assign a `void *` to a different kind of pointer (e.g. a `char **` variable or `int *`) without casting it explicitly to that type.  You can do that by writing the malloc calls this way:

```
char **words;
words = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*) * 200);
for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    words[i] = (char *) malloc(100);

int **index;
index = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int*) * 200);
for (i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    index[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000);
```

Casting the result from `malloc` is very unpopular these days, but if you have to use a compiler that considers implicit pointer casting to be an error, then the hell with that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler does not conform to the C standard: In C you are allowed to implicitely convert any `void*` to any other pointer (the opposite is also true). So the line

```
int* foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo));
```

is perfectly valid C code.

Your compiler, however, expects the following:

```
int* foo = (int*)malloc(sizeof(*foo));
```

to tell it that you really want to convert a `void*` to an `int*`. You can fix your code in an analog way.

---

Sidenote:
It's good to remember this, because C++ has the same problem as your compiler (with the only difference that in C++ it is the standard that overly picky). So in C++ the first variant is illegal as well.

Comment: IMHO, this is an argument against insisting that casting the result of malloc is always Bad and Wrong. If you don't know the user's compiler constraints, it may be counterproductive. In this case, telling the poster that she must not ever cast the result of malloc introduced more problems for her to solve, rather than eliminating them.